# login page, circular redirection+including a header

Tags: php, authentication, include

I have a problem with circular redirection on the page. I don't know how I can escape it. I have a header page with all the db connectivity and the session check for all the other pages. I need to include it into login page but I don't want the menu to be displayed on it, I only need the header for the db connectivity. 
But I cannot do it because since I have session check, I keep on getting the browser message 'circular redirection'. 
Is there any way to fix it and still have the header on the login page?
my code:
admin_header

```
<?php
session_start();
define('ADMIN',$_SESSION['username']);
if(!$_SESSION['username'])
{
header("location:admin_login.php");
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Project</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
    </head>

    <body id="home">
<div class="top" id="header">
<ul>

        <li><a class="menu" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="search.php">Add an Artist</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="contact.php">List the Artists</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="contact.php">Add a movie</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="contact.php">List the movies</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="contact.php">Add an admin</a></li>
        <
</ul>


</div>
<?php

 $server = 'localhost';
 $user = 'root';
 $pass = 'blablabla';
 $mydb = 'projectdb';
 $movies = 'movies';
 $artists='artists';
 $roll='roll';
 $users='Users';
 $connect = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass);
 mysqli_select_db($connect,$mydb)or die("cannot select DB");
session_start();
define('ADMIN',$_SESSION['username']);
if(!$_SESSION['username'])
{
header("location:admin_login.php");
}


?>
</body></html>
```

admin_login

```
<?php
include ('admin_header.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

    $login_form = <<<EOD
<form name="login" id="login" method="POST" action="">
<p><label for="username">Please Enter Username: </label><input type="text" size="40" name="username" id="username" value="" /></p>
<p><label for="password">Please Enter Password: </label><input type="password" size="40" name="password" id="password" value="" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/> <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="reset"/></p>
</form>
EOD;
if (isset($_GET['msg']))
{
$msg=$_GET['msg'];
if($msg!='') 
{
echo '<p>'.$msg.'</p>';
}
}

echo "<h1>Please enter your Login Information</h1>";
echo $login_form;
ob_start();

       $server = 'localhost';

 $pass = 'blablabla';
 $mydb = 'projectdb';
 $users='Users';
 $connect = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass);
 mysqli_select_db($connect,$mydb)or die("cannot select DB");
       if (!isset($_POST['username'])||!isset($_POST['password']))
       {
       echo "Please, enter your login information";
       }
       else
       {
       $username = $_POST['username']; 
       $password = $_POST['password'];
 if (!$connect)
       {
       echo ("Cannot connect to $server using $user");
       }
       $username = stripslashes($username);
       $password = stripslashes($password);
       $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$username);
       $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$password);
       $sql="SELECT * FROM $users WHERE username='".$username."' and password='".$password."'";
       $result=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
       $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
       if($count==1)
       {
       session_start();
       header("location:admin_index.php");
       $_SESSION["username"]=$username;
       $_SESSION["password"]=$username; 


       }
       else 
       { 
        $msg = "Wrong Username or Password. Please retry";
        echo $msg;
       }
       }
ob_end_flush();

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: If you only need some of your header file, why not separate it into two files? One with the HTML header, and one with the database connection? Then you can include just the part you need.

Comment: NEVER try to build you own login system if you have no idea what you are doing! Use a professional one instead!

Answer (score 1):

In admin_header change this code:

```
define('ADMIN',$_SESSION['username']);
if(!$_SESSION['username'])
{
header("location:admin_login.php");
}
```

with this:

```
if(!$_SESSION['username'] && $page != 'login')
{
header("location:admin_login.php");
} elseif(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
define('ADMIN',$_SESSION['username']);
}
```

and in admin_login add this line:

```
$page = 'login';
```

before you include the header.

**EDIT**

Try it with the elseif-condition to remove the undefined error

Comment: Thank you, @tfNetworX, but now i get the error 'undefined index 'username'

Comment: I've editied the Code and addet an elseif-condition to avoid the undefined error

Answer (score 0):

You have this twice in the code, once on top and once at the bottom. I would recommend putting it at the top of the script, and do the define after you have checked the session. Also, I added an extra check:

```
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['username'] && $page <> 'logon')
  {
  header("location:admin_login.php");
  }
define('ADMIN',$_SESSION['username']);
```

Then. In your admin logon:

```
<?php
$page = logon;
include ('admin_header.php'); 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you!!it stopped the redirection, but now writes 'undefined index 'username' in header :(